# Idlex confused about Python version

Tags: python, installation, pip, version, python-idle

I have downloaded the IDLE extension package IdleX (versionn 1.13) from the [main website](http://idlex.sourceforge.net/download.html). I have several versions of Python installed in my system:

- Python27 (C:\Python27)
- Python34 (C:\Python34)
- Python36 (C:\Program Files\Python36)

When I initially installed Idlex I had `C:\Python27` and `C\Python27\Scripts` in my system `path` variable. I would launch it by simply typing `Idlex` into the command terminal.

Now I would like to use Idlex for Python 3.6. After all, according to the link above:

> It will work with Python 2.6+ or 3.x series.

I started by removing python27 from my path variable and adding instead `C:\Program Files\Python36` and `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts`. Now from the command terminal:

```
C:\Users\aboufira>python --version
Python 3.6.2
```

which is good. I tried installing Idlex again by

- unzipping then running `idlex.py`
- installing using pip which gives the following:

  `C:\Users\aboufira>pip install Idlex`

  `Requirement already satisfied: Idlex in c:\users\aboufira\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages`

When I type `Idlex` into the command line it still launches it for python 2.7.3. Are there additional system parameters I am missing here?

**EDIT**

I also tried a `pip3` install

```
C:\Users\aboufira>pip install Idlex

Requirement already satisfied: Idlex in c:\users\aboufira\appdata\roaming\python
\python36\site-packages
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to install into your Python3 environment, e.g. `pip3 install ...`

Comment: tried that already. Please see edit. I am getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Idlex is not compatible with Python 3.6.0 and Python 3.6.1. It is, however, compatible with Python 3.5.3 32-bit and before. I had the same issue, until I found another post on StackOverflow: Idlex 1.13 : Unable to located "idlexlib"